# django session modified in get does not affect session in post

Tags: python, django, session, post, get

i'm facing a problem in modifying the request.session in a get request

assuming follwing code in the GET request:

The User can choose from a list of stings in a dropdown menu which is related to a dictionary groupids summarized in a key : value pair from the key, a string .

```
    if request.method == "GET":
        if 'group' in request.GET:
            # Remeber the group in the session
            # First attempt
            request.session['grouporsection'] = request.GET['group']
            # Second attempt
            request.POST.get('grouporsection', request.GET['group'])
            # Print modified session
            print 'GET session:', request.session.items()
            # And return the date form
            content = { 'form' : DateTimeForm(initial={'beg' : '10/24/2015',
                                                       'end' : '10/24/2015'}) }
        else:
            # If group not in request return the date form 
            # and all groups to the group search form
            content = { 'form' : DateTimeForm(initial={'beg' : '10/24/2015',
                                                       'end' : '10/24/2015'}), 
                        'allgroups' : ['FS', 'PS', 'LS', 'JS', '...', '.:.', ':.:', 'blabla', 'and so on'] }
```

which gives following result in the console when running the testserver:

```
GET session: [(u'grouporsection', 'FS'),
              (u'end', u'10/24/2015'), 
              (u'beg', u'10/24/2015')]
```

When the user now chooses a new date or not and hits the submit button
The request.method gets POST:

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print 'POST session:', request.session.items()
```

Which gives following output in the console:

```
POST session: [(u'grouporsection', None),
               (u'end', u'10/24/2015'), 
               (u'beg', u'10/24/2015')]
```

How do i modify grouporsection in the request.session in the GET request so that i can see if its been set in the POST request?
Or why does grouporsections disappear after the user selected a group from the dropdown list and then choosed a beg or end date or not in the upcoming DateTimeForm and hitted the submit button?

Thx in advance,
BigZ

Comment: Your question is not very clear, the most obvious conclusion is that you are modifying your session in some other part of the code not shown here. While the code sample iteself has dead code like request.POST.get('grouporsection', request.GET['group'])

Comment: Yeah, i modify the session in several parts of the code, reusing beg and end and some other stuff, like a the name of a colormap, in diffrent views, to plot some usage data for several groups which are summarized to sections. To keep the user from entering same things again i store the entries in the request.session as initial values for the forms showing up on the site. And i'm not sure if it's a problem with my understanding of request sessions or if the grouporsection variable gets overwritten in some other part. I'll take a look at my group.html and edit my question a little bit later